# 2 projects dependency in same solution causes unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ solution with two projects inside, one is a library, the other is an application depending on that library. When I use my library from the main projet it works fine.

I then added a graphical library that my own library depends on (SFML if that's relevent) and now my main projects spits `unresolved external symbol`.

Do I have to include the graphical library in my main project's dependency? I hope not because that's why I added the layer of my own library.

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: I successuly included my own library but the secondary library doesn't seem to be included in mine

Comment: ***secondary library doesn't seem to be included in mine*** You need to include `sfml` in your application as well. That is if your library is a static library. If your library is a .dll you can get rid of the dependency if your main application makes no direct use of sfml.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how would I include this dll in my main project ?